# Qnamaker API Replace Alteration

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have multiple QnA knowledgebases in our Qnamaker. I used QnaMaker API and successfully uploaded alterations data using PUT method

```
PUT https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/alterations
```

and I am able retrieve the same using the GET method

```
GET https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/alterations
```

But still my bot is not recognizing the alternate keywords. Any thoughts? 
Is there any limit on the max number of alternations that we can add.I uploaded around 1000 alternate keyword combinations.

For example:

In my Knowledge Base, here is one example question

What is Variable API?

I want the bot to identify "What is VariableAPI ?" and  "What is Variable API" as the same question and respond with the same answer. For this, I uploaded alternations using the  Qnamaker API ( PUT) method.

> > {   "wordAlterations": [
> >         {
> >           "alterations": [
> >             "Variable API",
> >             "VariableAPI"
> >           ]
> >         }
> >            ] }

Please, anyone, help me understand what I am doing wrong and why my QnAmaker can't identify them as different words

Comment: Hey @roney , I started working with QnA Maker service almost 1.5 years back when it was a free service with limited endpoint hit. That time there was a limit on the knowledge base data size but if you're using enterprise subscription, there shouldn't be any problem. Also, I would strongly recommend you to give all the alteration words in lowercase. And it would be really helpful if you can paste the api response ( along with confidence score ) please :)

Comment: @js__ any pointers to any such documentation that says we need to keep all the alterations in lowercase only?

Comment: I don't actually recall any such documentation but from my practical experience I would suggest you that. I could be wrong but my assumption is as the QnA maker uses a ML model behind the scenes, so whatever data you will feed there, would be used as standard. I remeber one of my cases where changing it to lowercase actually helped! PS, I have moved out from the "Bot zone" 8 months back so I could be wrong about current scenario!!